# How to count total words in a text file without using rstrip() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day!

I have the following snippets:

```
words_count = 0
lines_count = 0
line_max = None

file = open("alice.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    words = line.split()
    words_count += len(words)
    if line_max == None or len(words) > len(line_max.split()):
        line_max = line
    lines.append(line)

file.close()
```

This is using rstrip method to get rid of the white spaces in the file, but my exam unit do not allow the method rstrip since it was not introduced. My question is: Is there any other way to get the same result of `Total number of words: 26466` without using the rstrip?

Thank you guys!

Comment: are you allowed to use `strip`?

Comment: can you provide contents of a sample file? like maybe ~10 words

Comment: @rv.kvetch file can be found here -> https://files.catbox.moe/dz39pw.txt (should be saved as alice.txt) obviously. I cannot use **strip** either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly, this works for me without using `str.rstrip`:

```py
import requests

wc = 0
content = requests.get('https://files.catbox.moe/dz39pw.txt').text

for line in content.split('\n'):
    # line = line.rstrip("\n")
    words = line.split()
    wc += len(words)

assert wc == 26466
```

Note that a one-liner way of doing that in Python could be:

```py
wc = sum(len(line.split()) for line in content.split('\n'))
```

Comment: This works because the default separator of `split` is *any* whitespace. `rstrip('\n')` does not affect the word count in that way.

Comment: Nice one liner.